# Read large file in Fortran

Tags: fortran, text-files

The following code succeeded in reading txt files of 30x30 (7Kb) and 100x100 (69Kb) matrices of 1 and 0 values. Here, there is an example of a 3x3 matrix. The txt file "MyTxtFile.txt" reads as follows.

```
1 0 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

The code is presented bellow.

```
Integer,dimension(3,3):: ReadMatrix
Integer::row,col
open(12, file="MyTxtFile.txt")
do row=1,3
  read(12,*) (ReadMatrix(row,col),col=1,3)
end do
print*, ReadMatrix (1,:) !Print first row to check
```

As an output, I obtain the following

```
1 0 1
```

However, when I tried with a 1000x1000 matrix (3186 Kb) an error appeared saying the following:

```
At line 8 of file C:\Users\...\...\...  (unit=12, file='Matrix1000.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

What is actually happening and what are my options?

Comment: Note that the line `print*, ReadMatrix (:,1) !Print first row to check` actually prints the first *column* of `ReadMatrix`.  So now I'm worrying about your expertise in programming too ...

Comment: Why should we not think that there is a problem with file `Matrix1000.txt` ? Such as it not containing `10^6` values to read.  Is this a programming problem, or a data malformation problem ?

Comment: This was just a mistake when writing it here. I was using the 1000x1000 example, and I forgot to remove one zero.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I was using the same program to generate the 3x3, 100x100 and 1000x1000 matrices.  In the first two cases there were no problems. That is why,a priori, I do not think there is any problem with the file.

Comment: About the row and column thing, I am using symetric matrices so I did not bother too much. But thanks @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: @francescalus done!

Comment: you dont even need the loops here, just `read(12,*)readmatrix` (that will give the transpose....).   My bet theres something wrong with the file, check it isnt column wrapped

Comment: Using the in line looping as you might require temporary assignments by the compiler. Unless you have a specific and good reason to use this format, either use the recommendation of agentp to use a single read statement or a single loop with one read per line in the file. And tell us whether it worked :-)